# MySQL COUNT values changes when JOINing

Tags: mysql

I have a chapters table with about 17 entries all belonging to one book.

```
chapters:
 --------------------------
|  id  | book_id | content |
 --------------------------
|   1  |    1    |   ...   |
|   2  |    1    |   ...   |
|   3  |    1    |   ...   |
|   4  |    1    |   ...   |
|   5  |    1    |   ...   |
|  ... |    1    |   ...   |
 --------------------------
```

There is also a library table, which links users to the books they have saved:

```
library:
 ----------------
| user | book_id |
 ----------------
|   1  |    1    |
|   1  |    2    |
|   2  |    1    |
|   3  |    1    |
|   4  |    1    |
|  ... |    1    |
 ----------------
```

I can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chapters WHERE book_id = 1
```

and the table correctly outputs 17 because book 1 has 17 chapters

If I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM library WHERE book_id = 1
```

I also get the correct result of 5 because 5 users have added book 1 to their library.

However, I can't seem to combine the two queries together using JOIN. I want SQL code which will output something like this:

```
output:
 -----------------------------
|  book  | chapters | readers |
 -----------------------------
|    1   |    17    |    5    |
 -----------------------------
```

Comment: Your model misses a `books` table that should store `book_id`, book name and author etc. Your `library` table is an association table created for the many-to-many relationship between books and users.

Comment: @axiac A books table shouldn't store author.

Comment: @Strawberry you're right. I did the same mistake as the OP :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.book_id, count(c.id) as chapters, count(l.user) as readers
from chapters c
join library l on l.book_id = c.book_id
where c.book_id = 1
group by c.book_id
```

Comment: Nope, I seem to be getting book_id = 1, chapters = 17, readers = 17

Comment: You forgot to add distinct in count's parentheses. And group by is not necessary in this case. Should be like this: select c.book_id, count(distinct c.id) as chapters, count(distinct l.user) as readers

Answer (score 0):

//Check below:

```
select "1" as book,
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM chapters WHERE book_id = 1) as chapters, 
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM library WHERE book_id = 1) as readers
from dual;
```

Comment: unnecessary sub queries, expensive compared to a simple inner join.

Comment: Two counts in a large database should be less expensive than a join with aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

If tried a query like below your result set would include all rows in libary and chapters in this case 85 rows (17x5):

```
select c.book_id, c.id as chapters, l.user as readers
from chapters c
inner join library l on l.book_id = c.book_id
where c.book_id = 1;
```

> The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

You can read more [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

However in order to get the unique number of rows, ie. 17 chapter and 5 readers from your 85 record result set you have to use count distinct like below:

```
select c.book_id, count(distinct(c.id)) as chapters, count(distinct(l.user)) as readers
from chapters c
inner join library l on l.book_id = c.book_id
where c.book_id = 1;
```

You can read more about count distinct [here](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-distinct.php).

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer:

```
select c.book_id, count(distinct c.id) as chapters, count(distinct l.user) as readers
from chapters c
left join library l on l.book_id = c.book_id
where c.book_id = 1
```

or for all books:

```
select c.book_id, count(distinct c.id) as chapters, coalesce(count(distinct l.user), 0) as readers
from chapters c
left join library l on l.book_id = c.book_id
group by c.book_id
```